# How to convert an object with arrays as values to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is in this form:

```
{
    Health_id: [1, 2, 3],
    Epoch_Time: [16012,16013,16014],
    Disk_Free: ['86.2', '86.2','86.2'],
    Memory_Free: ['1555', '1552','1565'],
    CPU_Usage_Percent: ['6.7', '3.0', '2.7'],
    CPU_Time: ['24744.89','24749.60','24753.81']
}
```

I need to covert this into an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {'Health_id':1,'Epoch_Time':'16012','Disk_Free':'86.2','Memory_Free':'1555','CPU_Usage_Percent':'6.7','CPU_Time':'24744.89'}, 
    {'Health_id':2,'Epoch_Time':'16013','Disk_Free':'86.2','Memory_Free':'1552','CPU_Usage_Percent''3.0','CPU_Time':'24749.60'}, 
    {'Health_id':3,'Epoch_Time':'16014','Disk_Free':'86.2','Memory_Free':'1565','CPU_Usage_Percent': '2.7','CPU_Time':'24753.81'},
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am hoping that all the inner arrays have the same number of elements. You can try this way-

```js
const data = {
  Health_id: [1, 2, 3],
  Epoch_Time: [16012,16013,16014],
  Disk_Free: ['86.2', '86.2','86.2'],
  Memory_Free: ['1555', '1552','1565'],
  CPU_Usage_Percent: ['6.7', '3.0', '2.7'],
  CPU_Time: ['24744.89','24749.60','24753.81']
};

const res = [];
const keys = Object.keys(data);

for(let i = 0, l = data.Health_id.length; i < l; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  keys.forEach(key => obj[key] = data[key][i]);
  res.push(obj);
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple naive solution for your reference

```js
const convert = (old) => {
  const nRecords = old.Health_id.length;
  const nData = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < nRecords; index++) {
    nData.push({
      Health_id: old.Health_id[index],
      Epoch_Time: old.Epoch_Time[index],
      Disk_Free: old.Disk_Free[index],
      Memory_Free: old.Memory_Free[index],
      CPU_Usage_Percent: old.CPU_Usage_Percent[index],
      CPU_Time: old.CPU_Time[index],
    });
  }

  return nData;
};

let data = {
  Health_id: [1, 2, 3],
  Epoch_Time: [16012, 16013, 16014],
  Disk_Free: ["86.2", "86.2", "86.2"],
  Memory_Free: ["1555", "1552", "1565"],
  CPU_Usage_Percent: ["6.7", "3.0", "2.7"],
  CPU_Time: ["24744.89", "24749.60", "24753.81"],
};

data = convert(data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple `for loop` and the [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method you can just create the new objects.

```js
const data = {
   Health_id: [1, 2, 3],
   Epoch_Time: [16012,16013,16014],
   Disk_Free: ['86.2', '86.2','86.2'],
   Memory_Free: ['1555', '1552','1565'],
   CPU_Usage_Percent: ['6.7', '3.0', '2.7'],
   CPU_Time: ['24744.89','24749.60','24753.81']
};

const size = Object.values(data)[0].length;
const keys = Object.keys(data);
const result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  const options = keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = data[key][i];
    return acc;
  }, {})
  
  result.push(options);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```